# using register in ansible task

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to find a particular line in the `cat /etc/fstab`, register it in a variable and then want to use it to `umount` the found directory.

```
---
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root

  tasks:
  - name: Finding if the mount point exists
    shell: cat /etc/fstab | grep /mnt | awk '{print $2}'
    register: mountpoint

  - name: UMOUNT the mountpoint found in expression
    shell: umount "{{ item }}"
    with_items: mountpoint.stdout
```

I see the output works for first task. However in the second task it says, `"stderr": "umount: mountpoint.stdout: mountpoint not found", "stderr_lines": ["umount: mountpoint.stdout: mountpoint not found"]"`

Isn't it the register variable should work here? am i missing something?

**This is the output**

```
{
    "_ansible_parsed": true,
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "cmd": "cat /etc/fstab | grep /mnt | awk '{print $2}'",
    "end": "2017-09-29 15:07:12.717112",
    "_ansible_no_log": false,
    "stdout": "/mnt/dvd",
    "changed": true,
```

`stdout` is found here as /mnt/dvd. now  would like to `umount` it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should strongly consider using the `mount` action, which is idempotent by design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to workaround using following code by my own. More information about return values can be obtained from [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/common_return_values.html#stderr-lines).

```
---
  - hosts: all
    remote_user: root

    tasks:
    - name: Finding source source drive
      shell: cat /etc/fstab | grep /dev/sr0 | awk '{ print $2}'
      register: dest_path
    - name: Finding Destination path for Mount
      shell: cat /etc/fstab | grep /dev/sr0 | awk '{ print $1}'
      register: src_path

    - name: Mounting the data Drives
      mount:
        path: "{{ dest_path.stdout }}"
        src: "{{ src_path.stdout }}"
        fstype: auto
        opts: ro
        state: unmounted
```